# How do I properly graph a natural log?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I accidentally messed up my code and I can't manage to recreate it.

- [Here is the graph I'm currently getting with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc18g.jpg).
- [Here is the graph I aim to get/originally coded](https://m.imgur.com/a/PItf7QY):

I think the biggest problem is that whenever I implement my function `(4ln(2x+3)-1)` into my code, the graph stops and does not display the asymptote like before. If there's anyway someone could help I would appreciate it a lot!

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def function(x):
    return np.log(x)
x = np.arange(0.01,10,0.1)
y = 4*np.log(2*x+3)-1
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
plt.xlim(-5,10)
plt.ylim(-20,10)
plt.title('Graph of g(x)',fontsize=10)
plt.plot(x,y, color="blue",  linewidth=1, linestyle="-", 
              label="g(x)=4ln(2x+3)-1")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=8)
plt.ylabel('log',fontsize=8)
plt.savefig('Graph of g(x)', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
plt.grid()
plt.close()
```

Comment: What does "originally coded" mean? How does that code differ from this? (But you can see what is probably the right way in @j1-lee's answer below.)

Answer (score 0):

Your function `4*np.log(2*x+3)-1` has the asymptote at x = -3/2. Why don't you try

```
x = np.arange(-3/2 + 0.01, 10, 0.1)
```

instead?